# Facebook Login with Unity 5 - Always return me Graph API Error: Bad request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I just start write my first game with unity.

I Created on facebook app - in games category.

I downloaded Facebook idk and added to unity.
I changed app id in Facebook settings.

Now I tried my code:

```
public class LoginScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public string resultstr { get; set; }
    public Text LableResult { get; set; }

    List<string> perms = new List<string> (){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        LableResult = gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ();
        LableResult.text = "Test";
        if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK
            FB.Init (InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        } else {
            // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp ();
        }

    }

    private void InitCallback ()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp ();
            // Continue with Facebook SDK
            // ...
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            // Pause the game - we will need to hide
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log (aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log (perm);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("User cancelled login");
        }
    }

    // On Facebook login button
    public void OnFacebook ()
    {
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (perms, AuthCallback);
    }
}
```

But I'm ALWAYS getting in Result:

> Graph Api Error: 400 Bad request

And callback_id 2 (sometimes I've seen 3)

Login I try in Mock window with token from facebook.

I tried deploy on iPhone - and game just crashed when I click on login button

Answer (score 5):

Please to close this topic. I fixed it. It was my fail )) (Used app token instead user token )) (Happends)))))

Comment: Thanks for your notification which helps me recognize that I used app token too. lol

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me!

Remember to check the user token part, which won't be set by default!

[image: User permission]